# Mocking IdempotentConsumer

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm testing my app, that sends files from ftp to my computer and I'm checking not to copy one file twice. For this i use `IdempotentConsumer`.
My problem is that i can't run test, because this `IdempotentConsumer` always gives me error.
How can this be fixed?

Class

```
@Component
public class Converter extends SpringRouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

final XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
xmlJsonFormat.setTypeHints(String.valueOf("YES"));

from("ftp://Mike@localhost?" +
        "noop=true&binary=true&consumer.delay=5s&include=.*xml")
        .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileName"), FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(new File("data", "repo.dat")))
        .marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file://data").process(
        new Processor() {
            //System.out.println();
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Testing class

```
public class ConverterTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new Converter();
}

@Test
public void testAdvisedMockEndpoints() throws Exception {
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        replaceFromWith("direct:inputXML");
        interceptSendToEndpoint("file://data")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .to("mock:outXML");
    }
});        

    context.start();
    getMockEndpoint("mock:outXML").expectedMessageCount(1);        
    template.sendBody("direct:inputXML", "Test data");        
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: Test data]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.NoMessageIdException: No message ID could be found using expression: header(CamelFileName) on message exchange: Exchange[Message: Test data]
```

Comment: Please share the error (in detail) you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the context normaly `CamelFileName` header is added by the ftp component. 
But since your are injecting the message using direct in the test this might not be the case.

Try to adapt your test by adding the header manually with `.setHeader("CamelFileName", constant("msg01.txt"))`.